# SHARP Serialport RS232

Tags: powershell, serial-port, sharp

I am trying get Sony TV model from computer over Serialport.
Here is a documentation (page 80 - how to build query, page 83 - how to get model name).
https://cdn.cnetcontent.com/d1/9d/d19d926b-bb36-4ed3-bd03-af1cad4069da.pdf

Here is my simply script, but, unfortunatelly, always return *ERR*.
What I did wrong?

```
$hex = 0x4d,0x4e,0x52,0x44,0x31,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x0d
$com = New-Object System.IO.Ports.Serialport COM4,9600,None,8,one

$com.Open()
$com.Write($hex, 0, $hex.Count)

Start-Sleep -s 2
$read = $com.ReadExisting()
Write-Host "Response: $read" #ERR

$com.Close()
```

Comment: That manual says "When the input parameter is not within an adjustable range, "ERR" returns": so you are not sending a valid command. Also, as it is documented in letters rather than hex codes use a string and concert to ASCII (`System.Text.Encoding.ASCII` will do that).

Comment: Have you tried sending CR and LF, or LF instead of CR or alternatively omit the 0xd and use the WriteLine method?

Comment: @Richard the Write function is overloaded with both String and Byte[] parameter so as long as the hex bytes are correct it shouldn't matter and by default, SerialPort uses ASCIIEncoding to encode the characters.

Comment: @Remko tried but get same response :(

Comment: @Remko I assumed not, but that would make it easier to check the characters sent against the docs (and that is clearly where the problem lies)

Comment: @Richard trying by $com.WriteLine("MNRD1   "+"`r" ) but still have ERR (3 spaces)

Comment: WriteLine shouldn't need extra CR ?

Comment: @Remko without extra CR I got empty response (BytesToRead == 0).

Answer (score 0):

Found response: it return **ERR** wneh power is off.
When I powered on device over RS-232, script starts respond **LE740E** insteadof **ERR**